# Error with gulp-sass

Tags: npm, gulp, bower, gulp-sass

I get the following error when trying to run 'gulp serve':

> [14:14:52] Plumber found unhandled error:
>    Error in plugin 'gulp-sass'
>
> Message:
>       @import directives are not allowed inside mixins and functions
>
> Details:
>       fileName: ./bower_components/bootswatch/spacelab/_bootswatch.scss
>       lineNumber: 8

I upgraded to the latest node version. Ran "npm rebuild node-sass" and "npm rebuild gulp-sass". I tried reinstalling bower packages and npm packages. Is there any sort of assumption I can make. I can try to reinstall npm packages by hand, but there is about 50 and I am afraid it won't do anything.

Any pointers welcome. Will be here until I solve this. 'npm gulp-sass version' gives the same version as my team has and build works for all of them.

Comment: Have you checked your sass source for `@import` directives? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13879042/4231110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the original source of the Bower component you included and saw the following happening on the line mentioned there:

```
@mixin web-font($path){
  @import url("#{$path}");
}
```

As far as I know, "imports" are not allowed in `libsass` (which is the base for `gulp-sass`), as it would be a conditional import (which isn't allowed for various reasons) and could lead to possible errors. Ruby Sass is a little more forgiving there.

You might want use a different Bootswatch package there (like `bootswatch-sass`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solved it by copying file from my co-worker. We still don't know why they were different. What you pointed out was indeed the issue, but why it was there is another story altogether.