# @import using @if statement with SASS

Tags: sass

I'd like to import a colour palette using SASS and `@if` statement.

My code :

```
@if $look == default and not $look-chart-color or $look-chart-color == default {
      @import 'default';
}

@if $look == espacefourn and not $look-chart-color or $look-chart-color == espacefourn {
  @import 'espacefourn';
}

@if $look == ria and not $look-chart-color or $look-chart-color == ria {
  @import 'ria';
}
```

Issue : `Error: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.`

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879042/import-in-if-statement-in-sass

also: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/451

seems flakey tbh

Comment: I already found that ! But they have no solutions on these talk...

Comment: it's difficult mate - because, you're trying to define values before compile (while your output is always static)

- i wonder if you can use imports via css-variables /shrug