# SCSS variable scope

Tags: sass

I'm in the process of converting a stylesheet from *LESS* to *SCSS* and I'm confused about something I'm seeing with variable scope. Reproduced with a simple example:

```
$my-color: #000;

#logo {
    $my-color: #555;
    color: $my-color;
}

a {
    color: $my-color;
}
```

Converts to the following CSS:

```
#logo {
    color: #555555;
}

a {
    color: #555555;
}
```

The equivalent construction in *LESS* would result in the `a color` value being `#000` as the variable declaration within the `#logo` scope would override the more general one but only within that scope. Do variable scopes not work like that in *SCSS*? Is there a way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469931/sass-variable-default-scope ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading through the answers to [Sass variable default scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469931/sass-variable-default-scope) it seems that variables work differently in *SCSS* to *LESS*.

In this case the definition of `$my-color` in `#logo` changes the value of the global variable whereas in *LESS* it would be treated as a block local override of that global variable.

I guess I'll have to structure things a little differently in order to achieve the same result.

Comment: In my opinion this is bad, because you are polluting global space. You have to think up a new variable name every time you're entering to the new block, this leads to variable names: `$color`, `$color1`, `$color2` ....

Comment: Pretty soon Sass will have proper lexical scoping, and you'll be able to override global variables like this: `$var: newvalue !global;` -- Sass 3.3 already gives a deprecation warning when you override a global without `!global`.

Comment: Warning: This is no longer the case. See answer below.

Answer (score 26):

This is no longer the case at least as of SCSS v3.4.12:

Now it scopes correctly the variables:

Input:

```
$my-color: #000;

#logo {
    $my-color: #555;
    color: $my-color;
}

a {
    color: $my-color;
}
```

Output:

```
#logo {
  color: #555;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}
```

Can be tried out in: http://sassmeister.com/