# Use a mixins to change variable value

Tags: css, sass

I am generally quite new to sass and just wondered if it possible to define a new variable value, using mixins?

I thought it would be good to use a variable to define the padding size throughout the website I am building. The idea being that I could then use a mixin and media queries to define a new value.

An example might make more sense:

```
$site-padding:  40px;

@include media-over-767 {
    $site-padding: 20px;
}
```

I think this would be super useful but cannot get it to work... is there a method that works?

Comment: Even if @JinuKurian already answered, I think you should take a look at scoped variables in sass which may put you on another path to solve these sort of issues. Also, see the answer of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469931/sass-variable-default-scope) for more details about how variables works (mixins and scoped variables).

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a `sass` variable inside a breakpoint.

refer this issue - https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1227

You could simply do

```
$site-padding:  40px;
$site-padding-sm:  20px;

@include media-over-767 {
    padding: $site-padding-sm;
}
```

refer this too - [Using Sass Variables with CSS3 Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122195/using-sass-variables-with-css3-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

```
@mixin site-padding{
   $site-padding: 20px;
}

@include media-over-767 {
    @include site-padding;
}
```

Comment: How does site-padding translate to padding? Is there another mixin that breaks this down to adding a `padding: 20px`?

I have not run into this previously with sass.

Comment: The padding question is irrelevant to the answer, but if you need a mixin you could use to set the padding, here you go.

@mixin padding-all($top, $right, $bottom, $left) {
  padding-top: $top;
  padding-right: $right;
  padding-bottom: $bottom;
  padding-left: $left;
}

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what your looking for, but hopefully it gets you on the right path. Declare the mixin:

```
@mixin site-padding($padding:40px) {
    padding: $padding;
}
```

In that example, I set the mixin `site-padding` with a default value of `40px`.

Your SASS would look something like this:

```
.element {
     // Small screens
     @include site-padding(20px);

     // Over 767px
     @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        // Defaults to 40px. 
        @include site-padding();
     }
}
```